# Why are Array Prototype functions not working within an other array function like for each?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, prototype

I have the following issue I need to fetch some values from a other array while iterating.

But within the for each operation, the Array loses all its prototype functions.

```js
const allCrumbs: BreadCrumb[] = this.createBreadcrumbs(this.activatedRoute.root);

last.url.split('/').forEach((segment: string) => {
            if (segment !== '#') {
                // This is the part that doesn work within the array
    // Edit forgot null check here 
                const label = allCrumbs.find(value => value.url.endsWith(segment)).label;
                // allCrumbs.find(...) is not defined

                this.breadCrumbs.push({label: label ? label : segment, url: `/${segment}`});
            }
        });
    // This works just fine
    const testlabel = allCrumbs.find(value => value.url.endsWith('test')).label;
```

when I do this, the error:

> allCrumbs.find(...) is not defined

appeard.

When I do the same outside the scope of the Other array, it works fine.

Can someone explain this behaviour ?
And maybe give a hint to a solution.

Thank you very much:

**Solution**

Forgot a nullcheck, thank you  .

this works now

```
last.url.split('/').forEach((segment: string) => {
            if (segment !== '#') {

                const result = allCrumbs.find(value => value.url.endsWith(segment));

                this.breadCrumbs.push({label: result ? result.label : segment, url: `/${segment}`});
            }
        });
```

Shame on me. But Thank you all for you Patience

Comment: What's the value of `allCrumbs` when it is failing if you `console.log(allCrumbs)`?

Comment: There error is not about the `.find` function but about the value *returned* by the `.find` function. Looks like `value.url.endsWith(segment)` is not `true`, thus `allCrumbs.find(...)` returns `undefined`. Since we don't know what the value of `segment` and `allCrumbs` are, all we can do is suggest to code defensively, i.e. verify that `allCrumbs.find(...)` returns a valid value before you do something with it.

Comment: its not only "find" its also filter, foreach, everything that is a prototype Function. 
It works outside. but not Prototype function seems to be "defined" whenn accessing it within a other arrowfunction

Comment: Oh thank you, yes you are right, there was no nullcheck if ther is no result. thats why filter and find woun't work.
@Felix

Comment: *"It works outside. but not Prototype function seems to be "defined" whenn accessing it within a other arrowfunction"* I highly doubt that.

Comment: Please supply us with an [mcve] - as it stands, we can only guess at what's wrong and we could guess wrong. Essentially, either `allCrumbs` had different data to what you expect or `segment` is not what you expect.

Comment: FWIW, if the issue was indeed that the method doesn’t exist, you would get an error that’s similar to “undefined is not a function”. Also the fact that the error includes “(...)” after the function name is an indication that it is about the return value of the function call, not the property/function itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `.find()` is not finding anything based on your predicate. So it returns undefined.

Instead, expect that it might return undefined and handle accordingly. Attempt to find the matching value first:

```js
const crumb = allCrumbs.find(value => value.url.endsWith(segment));
```

And then depending on which version of Angular (and therefore Typescript) you are using, you can either using optional chaining or a ternary expression to get the label.

Angular >= v9

```js
const label = crumb?.label;
```

Angular < v9

```js
const label = crumb ? crumb.label : '';
```

```js
const allCrumbs: BreadCrumb[] = this.createBreadcrumbs(this.activatedRoute.root);

last.url.split('/').forEach((segment: string) => {
  if (segment !== '#') {
    const crumb = allCrumbs.find(value => value.url.endsWith(segment));
    const label = crumb ? crumb.label : '';
    this.breadCrumbs.push({
      label: label ? label : segment, 
      url: `/${segment}`
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Ah, the good old not testing for a property's existence before accessing it...